# Cancel an axios request, when not having the fetch in useEffect

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to implement the cancel request function for my axios post. I created own js files for the functions and I am importing them into my screens. Here is an example

App.js

```
        cancelToken.current = axios.CancelToken.source()
        async function getFeed() {
        let x = await service.getUserFeed(user_id, cancelToken);
        setData(x); }
getFeed();
      return () => {
         cancelToken.cancel();
                               }
   },[user_id]);
```

service.js:

```
 getUserFeed: async (token, user_id, source) => {
        let x;
        await axios.post(Default.apiEndpoint + 'feed',
            {

            },
            {
                cancelToken: source.token,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': "application/json",
                    'Content-Type': "application/json",
                    'user_id': user_id,
                }
            }).then(response => {
                x = response.data;
            }).catch(error => {
                if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
                    console.log('Request canceled', error.message);
                }
                else {
                    x = error.response.status;
                }
            });
        return x;
    },
```

If I am calling the request in the hook itself it is working. So I am not even sure, if it is possible, because the request is not triggered, when the user leaves the page. So I would need to cancel the request in the service.js itself (I guess). Did anyone implement that already and can help me here?

Thanks